# Show immediately data in datagridview After the Insertion/Updating

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures

I know it's been asked many times here in SOF but i assure you i tried everything like .refresh, .update, call the method after the insertion etc. but still nothing happen i need to refresh my user control again just to see the new data change in datagridview. I'm using stored procedure to display data on my datagridview also for inserting, updating etc. I hope someone would be able to help me to pin point what i do wrong or what i've missed. Thank you

Here's my class for displaying data on my datagridview

```
public static class Display 
{
    public static void Display_Customer(DataTable dt, DataGridView dgv)
    {     
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesInventoryManagement.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetCustomers", con))
            {               
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    var bsource = new BindingSource();
                    bsource.DataSource = dt;
                    dgv.DataSource = bsource;
                    sda.Update(dt);
                }
                con.Close();    
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Here's my usercontrol where my controls like datagridview, button etc

```
 public partial class ManageCustomer : UserControl
{
    public ManageCustomer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private void ManageCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Display.Display_Customer(dt, CustomersList);   
        Customization._DGVWidth(CustomersList);
    }
    private void CustomersList_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Register.CustomerSelection(CustomersList, lbl_id, lbl_name, lbl_gender, 
        lbl_contact,lbl_email, lbl_address, PreviewImage);      
    }
    private void Btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var uc = new UpdateCustomer(this).ShowDialog();
    }
    private void CustomersList_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = CustomersList.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Variables.ID = row.Cells["Customer ID"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Here's a form that get's the data from datagridview based on ID
PS: Btn_Update show new form to my usercontrol

```
public partial class UpdateCustomer : Form
{
    ManageCustomer _view;
    public UpdateCustomer(ManageCustomer view)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateC.CustomerInformation(Variables.ID, lbl_path, PreviewImage, txt_name, txt_contact, txt_email, txt_address);
        this._view = view;
    }
    private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesInventoryManagement.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            UpdateC._Update(lbl_path.Text, txt_name.Text, txt_contact.Text, txt_email.Text, txt_address.Text);
            Display.Display_Customer(_view.dt, _view.CustomersList);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, Here's my stored proc

```
USE [SalesInventory]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetCustomers]

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
                SELECT   CustomerID as 'Customer ID', Images, Full_Name, Gender, Contact_Number as 'Contact Number', Email, Home_Address as 'Address'
                FROM Customer_List      
END
```

Comment: Sometimes it helps to assign `null` before assigning the changed data: `dgv.DataSource = null; dgv.DataSource = bsource;`. Otherwise, if the `DataTable` is the same, the dgv might not realize the update.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes What do you mean by that? where should i assign to null the datagridview ?

Comment: Just before `dgv.DataSource = bsource;`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes well doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the code you have posted and managed to get the GridView refreshed without having to reload.

Please change the Display class as below

```
    public static void Display_Customer3(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesInventoryManagement.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetCustomers", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();     // Initiate the datatable here to avoid getting duplicate data during 'sda.Fill(dt)'
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    var bsource = new BindingSource();
                    bsource.DataSource = dt;
                    dgv.DataSource = bsource;
                    //sda.Update(dt);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Update rest of the code where `Display.Display_Customer` is referenced to appropriately.

```
Display.Display_Customer(CustomersList);
```

Or

```
Display.Display_Customer(_view.CustomersList);
```

With the above changed, I managed to refresh the `DataGridView` upon update.

**Update** to enable DataGridView Search:

Since `BindingSourse` is used as the DataSource, you can utilize the `BindingSourse.Filter` to enable the search. Update the Search textbox as below;

```
BindingSource dgBS = (BindingSource)CustomersList.DataSource;
dgBS.Filter = string.Format("FileName LIKE '%{0}%'", txtFilter_FileName.Text);
```

Comment: @Diether, please refer the updated answer on how to enable search.